# <a href> link to page prints space?

Tags: html, css, href

My `Hyperlink Reference` links to my page properly, but the `navigation bar` now prints a few spaces before the text. I think I know why this is, but I'm not sure how to fix this.

My HTML:

```
            <li class="current_page_item"> <a href="#" accesskey="1" title=""> <a href="index.html"> Homepage </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#" accesskey="4" title=""> <a href="resume/resume.doc"> R&egrave;sum&egrave; </a> </a> </li>
```

My CSS:

```
#menu{
    position: absolute;
    top: 2em;
    right: 0;
}

#menu ul{
    /* display: inline-block; */
    margin-left: -4px;
}

#menu li{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I think my problem is in the CSS. I commented out `display: inline-block;` because that is the default space for `href` links. Instead, I tried to take 4 spaces off which is why I used the `-4px;`. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Remove the sapces from your HTML

Comment: @Amir multiple spaces in HTML are interpreted as a single space !

Comment: @webNeat Only when they're next door to each other, surely. The tags between them give the effect of adding some `&nbsp;`s to the code.

Comment: @worldofjr sure, you are right.
@ChriskOlson try to add `padding-left: 0px;` to `#menu ul`

Comment: @worldofjr that doesn't seem to be it. I have no idea what it could be

Comment: @webNeat what do you mean by the spaces? It doesn't seem to do anything differently when I delete them

Comment: @webNeat I know but I mean delete the spaces to remove the one space displayed on screen

Comment: One of your `<a>`'s is not closed. That never helps in cases like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, remove any white space you have between your `<a>` tags as that will add spaces.

What I think you might have as a problem though is some space between your list items. If you want to keep the list items on separate lines then that's fine, but avoid any white space between the closing and opening `<li>` tags, like this;

```
<li><a ... </a></li><li>
<a ... </a></li><li>
<a ... </a></li>
```

This should close the gap between the list elements.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is it! I never knew that spaces in the code affected how the code looks. Thank you both so very much!

Comment: Check this for more references on how to fight whitespace between inline-block elements: [http://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block](http://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block)

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to your css file and remove all the blank spaces given in html file.

```
 li{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
 }
```